# program to read data from a text file and display the output in abbreviated form with all punctuation marks as entered my the user

Tags: python

the text file looks like: textabbrv.txt

r:are

u:you

ttyl:talk to you later

l8:late

brb:be right back

i tried a lot to fix this, but there is one error, my program is:

```
def main():

    indexEntries={}
    infile=open('textabbrv.txt','r')
    fields=extractRecord(infile)
    while len(fields)>0:
        set_entries(indexEntries,fields[1],fields[0])
        fields=extractRecord(infile)
    infile.close()
    printIndex(indexEntries)

def extractRecord(infile):

    line=infile.readline()
    if line!="":
        fields=line.split(":")
        page=fields[0].rstrip()
        term=fields[1].rstrip()
        return [page,term]
    else:
        return []

def set_entries(entries,term,page):


       pageSet=set([page])
       entries[term]=pageSet

def printIndex(entries):

    user_input=input("Enter a message to be translated: \n")


    if user_input!=" ":
        user_split=user_input.replace(","," ").replace("?"," ").replace("!"," ").\
                    replace(":"," ").replace(";"," ").split(" ")


    print()
    print("The translated text is: ")

    for long_form in entries:
        sentence=entries[long_form]

        for short_form in sentence:
            if short_form in user_split:
                print(user_input.replace(short_form,long_form))




main()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter a message to be translated: 
ttyl,brb

The translated text is: 

talk to you later,brb

ttyl,be right back
```

but the output should look like this and should be translated in just one line, i think i messed up somewhere in the for loops a the end of the program

```
Enter a message to be translated: 
ttyl,brb

The translated text is: 

talk to you later,be right back
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the output you see is due to this:

```
print(user_input.replace(short_form,long_form))
```

Whenever you find a match, you replace *that* match in the *original* user input, and print it out, but you don't store that modified version of the original input at all.

You could fix that by doing:

```
user_input = user_input.replace(short_form,long_form)
```

and then printing the new version of `user_input` at the end of `printIndex`. Now, that may be problematic, but that's another story.

In any case... the way you have approached this is a bit unusual. You are populating the `indexEntries` dictionary in the *reverse* way that I would expect. You put the indices as the values! Instead:

1) I would import `csv` and rewrite this:

```
infile=open('textabbrv.txt','r')
fields=extractRecord(infile)
while len(fields)>0:
    set_entries(indexEntries,fields[1],fields[0])
    fields=extractRecord(infile)
infile.close()
```

as:

```
with open('textabbrv.txt','r') as infile:
    for (field1, field2) in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=':'):
        indexEntries[field1] = field2
```

In the process I'm getting rid of `extractRecord` and `set_entries`. Now the dictionary looks like `{'brb': 'be right back', 'r': 'are, ...}`

2) You're splitting the user input, but then you don't make use of that. Let's rewrite this:

```
for long_form in entries:
    sentence=entries[long_form]

    for short_form in sentence:
        if short_form in user_split:
            print(user_input.replace(short_form,long_form))
```

and make it:

```
output = []
for word in user_split:
    # The following could be written as
    # output.append(entries.get(word, word))
    if word in entries:
        output.append(entries[word])
    else:
        output.append(word)

print ','.join(output)
```